# How to use a variable as a property ID in a Wikidata SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

This query can return both the ID (?ID) for the property and the item ID, but I can't seem to get it to use the property ID (?ID) in a triplet.

SPARQL is a dark art to me. Thank you for your help.

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?superpower ?property ?label ?ID ?superpowerLabel
WHERE
{
  
  ?property a wikibase:Property ;
        schema:description ?label . 
  
  filter contains(?label,"super") 
  filter contains(?label,"abilities") 
  
  ?item rdfs:label "Wolverine"@en .
  # Get the ID
  BIND(REPLACE(STR(?property), "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/", "wdt:") AS ?ID)
  ?item ?ID ?superpower   . # This part works with "wdt:P2563" instead of ?ID.
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}

LIMIT 10
```

Comment: https://w.wiki/4yY5 оr https://w.wiki/4yY7, see https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: Solution by Stanislav Kralin in the comments**

> w.wiki/4yY5 оr w.wiki/4yY7, see m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format –
> Stanislav Kralin

```
WHERE
{
  
  ?property a wikibase:Property ;
        schema:description ?label . 
  
  filter contains(?label,"super") 
  filter contains(?label,"abilities") 
  
  ?item rdfs:label "Wolverine"@en .
  # Get the ID
  BIND(URI(REPLACE(STR(?property), STR(wd:), STR(wdt:))) AS ?ID)
  ?item ?ID ?superpower   . # This part works with "wdt:P2563" instead of ?ID
  hint:Prior hint:runLast true .
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}

LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use the second solution suggested by Stanislav, i.e. the direct mapping between the properties namespace, i.e. `?property a wikibase:Property ;
        schema:description ?label ;
              wikibase:directClaim ?ID` - but indeed just a matter of taste

Comment: if you don't mind, you can accept your own answer such that it will basically be marked as "done"

Comment: Thank you. I have to wait 24 hours before accepting my answer. BTW: Is there a thread somewhere where I can post other SPARQL/Wikidata questions like this?